# How to pass data with '&amp;' between web pages

Tags: php, javascript, post, jquery

The jQuery -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",  
        url: "add_showcase.php",  
        data: "title=" + document.getElementById("title_in").value + "&desc=" + document.getElementById("desc_in").value,
        success: function(html)....
```

When i pass this data as "desc" -

```
<object width="480" height="385">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7M-jsjLB20Y?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/7M-jsjLB20Y?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

add_showcase.php only receives a part of this data -

```
desc=<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7M-jsjLB20Y?fs=1
```

What would you do if you were to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `&` with the hex value `%26` so it looks like `http://www.youtube.com/v/7M-jsjLB20Y?fs=1%26hl=en_US`

To do this, use Javascript's [`escape()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function. If you need to, use Javascript's `unescape()` function to convert the hex values back to their original values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` instead of `GET` if you have huge data

Comment: Tried it with POST, gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
escape(document.getElementById("desc_in").value)
```